# How can I modify delivery(message) inside custom exchange for RabbitMQ 3.5.6?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am writing custom exchange for RabbitMQ which must take arguments from exchange and put them to message headers. I am not very familiar with Erlang.

```
-module(rabbit_exchange_type_arguments_to_headers).


-include_lib("rabbit/include/rabbit.hrl").
-include_lib("rabbit/include/rabbit_framing.hrl").

-behaviour(rabbit_exchange_type).

%% API
-export([
  description/0,
  serialise_events/0,
  route/2,
  validate/1,
  validate_binding/2,
  create/2,
  delete/3,
  policy_changed/2,
  add_binding/3,
  remove_bindings/3,
  assert_args_equivalence/2
]).

-rabbit_boot_step(
  {?MODULE,
    [{description, "exchange type argument-to-header"},
      {mfa,         {rabbit_registry, register, [exchange, <<"argument">>, ?MODULE]}},
      {cleanup, {rabbit_registry, unregister, [exchange, <<"argumente">>]}},
      {requires,    rabbit_registry},
      {enables,     kernel_ready}]
  }
).


description() ->
  [{name, <<"argument">>},
   {description, <<"Adds exchange argumets to message headers">>}].


serialise_events() -> false.

% This is classic fanout routing
route(#exchange{name = Name, arguments = Arguments},
    #delivery{message = #basic_message{content = #content{properties = #'P_basic'{headers = MessageHeaders}}}} = Delivery) ->

  Headers = make_headers(MessageHeaders, Arguments),

  NewDelivery = Delivery#delivery{message = #basic_message{content = #content{properties = #'P_basic'{headers = Headers}}}},

  % Do some thing here to send NewDelivery instead of old one

  rabbit_router:match_routing_key(Name, ['_']).


make_headers(undefined, undefined) -> [];
make_headers(undefined, Arguments) -> Arguments;
make_headers(Headers, undefined) -> Headers;
make_headers(Headers, Arguments) -> lists:append(Headers, Arguments).

validate_binding(_X, _B) -> ok.


validate(_Exchange) -> ok.
create(_Tx, _X) -> ok.
deladd_binding(_Tx, _X, _B) -> ok.
remove_bindings(_Tx, _X, _Bs) -> ok.
assert_args_equivalence(Exchange, Args) ->
  rabbit_exchange:assert_args_equivalence(Exchange, Args).
ete(_Tx, _X, _Bs) -> ok.
policy_changed(_X1, _X2) -> ok.
```

I made new Delivery inside of rout method, but as I know I can't modify  original variable in Erlang so Rabbit proceed with original one.

Is there some way to modify message inside exchange or say to rabbit proceed with new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. 
If someone interesting see my repository https://github.com/thecederick/rabbitmq-arguments-to-headers-exchange .
There are source code and artifact ready for usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the source code, everything is possible.